# how to append directory name and date as backup file suffix?

Tags: bash, shell

I need to make a script to backup of files, and I would like to have a timestamp and base file name as part of the name to make it easier to differentiate.

```
#!/bin/bash
filename=$(basename $(pwd))
echo $filename

output_dir="/home/backup/backup_$filename_$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%Hh%Mm%Ssec)/"
echo $output_dir
```

**Getting following output :-**

```
bash-4.2$ ./backup_1.sh
test
/home/backup/backup_2018-08-21_10h44m10sec/
bash-4.2$
```

In output_dir name filename "**test**" not included only timestamp added as suffix. Expected output is "**/home/backup/backup_test_2018-08-21_10h44m10sec/**"

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need braces around your variable

```
${filename}
```

Replace your code with this

```
output_dir="/home/backup/backup_${filename}_$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%Hh%Mm%Ssec)/"
```

With the current code, bash is trying to find ${filename_} which does not exist.

Updated Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename=$(basename $(pwd))
echo $filename

output_dir="/home/backup/backup_${filename}_$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%Hh%Mm%Ssec)/"
echo $output_dir
```

Output

```
test
/home/backup/backup_test_2018-08-21_11h02m55sec/
```

Comment: Suraj...if this works for you...can you accept it as an answer for your query which helps me to fetch some points..